# EXCEL Sumifs to PowerBI

Tags: excel, powerbi, sumifs

I have a formula in Excel that gives me the sum of several cells if two conditions are met.

In Excel, the base has been converted into a table so that this works.

The formula is as follows:

```
=sumifs(B:B,B:B,">0",A:A,"<="&[@ month])
```

In A I have sales and in B the month. If I have sales in A that are greater than 0, it should add up all sales for the months if the month of the line is less than or equal to the own month.

In Power BI, it only sums up all months from start to finish if the value is greater than 0, but not the amount of sales for the one month.

| month | sales | sumifs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | 737 |
| 1 | 237 | 737 |
| 2 | 420 | 1157 |
| 3 | 380 | 1537 |
| 4 | 410 | 2437 |
| 4 | 280 | 2437 |
| 4 | 210 | 2437 |
| 5 | 0 | 2437 |

[image: Table and output]

Comment: Edit you question; Add some dummy data and desired output;

Comment: Your SUMIFS formula doesn't show the sales for one month either.  Do you want two columns for your output? One for the month sales and another running total?  Or something else?

Comment: Hey, i changed the formula that it fits the wanted output. Sometimes i have a moth 2 or 3 times and sometimes only one time in the table. so i have to sum them if it is the same month plus the previous months

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Measure 2 = CALCULATE( sum(Table[sales]), FILTER(ALL(Table), Table[month] <= SELECTEDVALUE(Table[month])))
```

[image]

Comment: Gives me just an empty column

Comment: How do you use this (this should be a measure), put to the visualization month column? I test this on your sample and it gives mi correct results.

Comment: my fault sorry. i didnt want it as a measure. i put it in a table. in the measure itself it works. can i get in in the table itself?

Comment: I don't get what you need. You need a new table with only one Column Sumif?

Comment: I want to add it to the table where the data comes from. So i add in the Table "New Column" and enter the formula there. Is that possible?

Comment: why you need this as a physical column? How to you want to use this new column?

Answer (score 0):

just create a new measure (or calculated column).

```
Sumif = SUMX('Tablename','Tablename'[sales])
```

Comment: It just gives me the output of 2437 in all month and not only in 4 and above

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the result as a separate column, you can do it with two queries:

### Load_Data

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content]
in
    Source
```

### Calc_Sum

1. Group by month and sum up sales to get result per month
2. Add original data via month and show sales column to re-include the original sales
3. Rearrange the columns in case the order is relevant for you

```
let
    Source = Load_Data,
    Group = Table.Group(Source, {"month"}, {{"Sum_of_sales", each List.Sum([sales]), type nullable number}}),
    AddOriginalData = Table.NestedJoin(Group, {"month"}, Load_Data, {"month"}, "Load_Data", JoinKind.RightOuter),
    ShowSales = Table.ExpandTableColumn(AddOriginalData, "Load_Data", {"sales"}, {"sales"}),
    Rearrange = Table.ReorderColumns(ShowSales,{"month", "sales", "Sum_of_sales"})
in
    Rearrange
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Dax in a Calculated Column. It worked for me with your Data

```
SUMIF = CALCULATE( 
        SUM(Table[Sales]), 
        FILTER(ALL(Table), Table[Month] <= EARLIER((Table[Month]))),
        Table[Sales] > 0
        )
```

[image: Result]

Do let me know if it worked for you.

Have a good day !!

Best Regards,
Pratik